# how to add different Href and onCick in ANCHOR TAG for a Ajaxed based website?

Tags: javascript, anchor, right-click, mouseleftbuttondown

I am developing a Ajax based web application.I want to add HREF and OnClick, both to the **anchor tag**.

This I want to do because of 2 reasons,

1. To keep the web application SEO friendly.'
2. Secondly, if user does a "left click event" in that case I want to call AJAX query and in case of "right click event", I want to open a page in new TAB or Window.

I was trying following code but its not working.

```
<A href="http://www.website.com/" onClick="alert("right click event fired"); return false;">stuff</A>
```

My question is, Is it possible to achieve case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might work

```
  <A href="http://www.website.com/" onClick="alert('right click event fired');return false;">stuff</A>
```

the double quotes were getting closed in the middle..